# oracle error in windows-7 64bit

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle, oracle11g

I installed windows-7 64 bit.  When I try to run my program (that works with Oracle 11g) I get this error:

```
Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException 
this problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed
```

What can be the problem ? Where I can download 64 bit oracle client ?

(can I get any link for download)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried download the 64bit Oracle Client from:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win64soft-094461.htmlBlockquote

This looks like it might be the correct download:

> Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client (11.2.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (x64)
>   win64_11gR2_client.zip (615,698,264 bytes) (cksum - 2947608743)
>   Contains the Oracle Client Libraries. Download if you want the client libraries only

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you cannot obtain a 64 bit version of the Oracle client and are stuck with the 32 bit version, then you can either:

1. rebuild your .NET application to
   only run as a 32 bit (x86) process
   instead of "Any CPU" or
2. use [CorFlags.exe (CorFlags
   Conversion Tool)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=VS.100%29.aspx1.) to reconfigure
   your existing .NET application exe
   to run as 32 bit without having to
   rebuild it.